# Lotus Notes error

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

When I execute a script for updating calender entries for 6 months I got this error. Please help me how to solve this error.

Error: updating search context has encountered a problem  when executing one Lotus script

Comment: Please post your script and the line where error occurs.

Comment: When I execute script, I sometimes also get an error. Can you help me? Without code, this question is not answerable...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your code is not finding the proper document. Test your code in the debugger if you use the tab to look at values. You will see that the search is not working.

I would switch from a search based code to a document collection search if you don't have that many documents to look at.

You might even set a flag on a document when you save the doc so you can find it later... This would be a change of code to the save button.

There are many ways to fix this issue.